# Git Bash on windows how to modify default configuration script (eg to set aliases)

Tags: git, bash, sh, git-bash

I was wandering how to automatically run some script (eg to set environment and aliases) when running All Programs->Git->Git Bash

Answer (score 0):

I found right clicking on Git Bash->Properties->tab Shrotcut-> edit-field "Start In" is set as %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%

or alternatively when Git Bash starts you can write `pwd`

Then you can just add to that path file with magic name `.bashrc`

Then you can put all the goodies you want there like:

```
alias ll="ls -all"
alias proj="cd /d/Data/vbe/ghd_josh"
```